# Let $A$ be a $5\times 3$ matrix and let $rank(A)=3$ then which from these two statements is right:

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

a)for every matrix $B$ thats $3\times 3$, and $rank(B)=3$, for the equation $(AB)x=0$ theres a unique solution. 
b)for every matrix $B$ thats $5\times 5$, and $rank(B)=5$, for the equation $(BA)x=0$ theres infinitely number of solutions. 
 
What I know is that the rank of $(AB)$ or $(BA)$ can be at most 3. which makes me think that they both can be correct. but the answer is a and I can't understand why.

 any assistance or explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out the main question. Could you, please, state the problem in a more obvious way (with some *"If $X$, then prove $Y$"* statements maybe)?

Comment: @VIVID hey sorry if it wasn't understandable, the question says if $A$ is a $5\times 3$ matrix and $rank(A)=3$, then which of these two statements is right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that from the associativity $(BA)x = B(Ax)$ . Since rank of $B$ is $5$,the only solution for the equation $By=0$ is $y=0$, so it is enough to check the equation $Ax = 0$. Similarly, since rank of $A$ is $3$ ,the only solution of  $Ax = 0$ is $x=0$. Thus, b) is not correct. Using the same idea, you can show that a) is correct as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to make sure I understood it right I'll try to show that a is correct, since $A$ is a $5\times 3$ matrix and $r(A)=3$ then the equation $Ay=0$ has only one trivial solution which is $y=0$, and $r(B)=3$ and $B$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, then the equation $Bx=0$ has only one solution which is $x=0$, then all $A(Bx)=0$ has only one solution. is this okay?

Comment: Yes, it is okay.

Comment: Appreciate the help :) thanks again